# Axios baseUrl change from http to https

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ssl, axios

I have a react application which communicates with server on a domain (e.g. [www.servdomain.com](http://www.servdomain.com)). I added SSL on [www.servdomain.com](http://www.servdomain.com) and I enabled force redirect so the react application is not working anymore. So I guessed there might be a setting for the server address to change `http` to `https`.

I found this file: `axios-instance.js` with this content:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const instance = axios.create({
     baseURL:'http://servdomain.com/server/index.php/'
});

export default instance;
```

Can I just change `http` to `https` and enable force redirect again? Is that simple? Or do I need to rebuild the project etc.?

**DISCLAIMER:I have no idea of react applications.**

Comment: It's pretty unclear to me what your actual problem is. But when you have https enabled on your API, you can simply modify the baseURL to https? When your requests still fail, the issue might be something else.

Comment: @maio290 the problem is that I havent try to change http to https because I am not sure if its just that edit or I need to rebuild the project etc.